# Использование скриптов для формы обратной связи

Tags: php, javascript, html, веб-программирование, html5

Необходимо было создать форму обратной связи на сверстанный сайт, поиски в интернете в конце концов всегда приводили к использованию Php кода для формы обратной связи. Скажите, возможно ли эффективно использовать JS скрипт для передачи данных в форме обратной связи?
И какой способ используете Вы?

Comment: Использовать js возможно, если у вас на сервере nodejs.

Comment: Есть сервисы которые позволяют хостить формы(в том числе и обратной связи). Если пользоваться одним из них то можно обойтись без хостинга своего скрипта. Решение будет зависить от требований бизнеса(законов). Как правило они стоят деньги, некоторые из них предлогают бесплатный план, но он обычно не очень. Примером такого сервиса может быть https://www.zoho.com/. Just google it ;)

Comment: https://formspree.io/ - пользовался вот этим.

Comment: @YozhEzhi, а чем теперь пользуетесь? И нормально ли использование стороннего сервиса для создание рабочей контактной формы или лучше иметь под рукой готовый php скрипт и вставлять при необходимости?

Answer (score 0):

Можно вообще без формы

```html
<a href="mailto:my@email.com">Обратная связь</a>
```

Только спам пойдет, лучше email зашифровать.